# Using power series to solve second order D.E.; Is there a trick to finding out what/where to shift?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> $xy''-y'-4x^3y=0$

I'm not looking for solutions, just hints/tips.
\begin{align}y=&\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nx^n \\[0.2cm]
\dot y=&\sum^\infty_{n=2}(n)a_nx^{n-1}\\[0.2cm]
\ddot y=&\sum^\infty_{n=2}(n-1)(n)a_nx^{n-2} \\[0.2cm]
&\sum^\infty_{n=?}(n-1)(n)a_nx^{n-1} - \sum^\infty_{n=2}(n)a_nx^{n-1} - \sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nx^{n+3}  =0\end{align}

I find that I spend more time figuring out how to shift the indices so that they all start at the same place, and making the exponent above x is identical than actually solving the recurrence relation and other steps.

Is there a trick/quick method? An algorithm maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it, is first I choose the exponent I want on all the $x$'s.  There's almost never a reason you can't choose $n$.  Then I look at the exponent and see what I have to increase or decrease it by, in order to make it $n$.  In your first sum, I need to increase the $n$'s by $1$.  That means I need to decrease the limits of the sum by $1$.  So $n=2$ becomes $n=1.$ (And infinity becomes infinity minus 1, which is infinity, contrary to what my little brother insists.) The last sum needs all the $n$'s in the summand decreased by $3$, so the limits are increased by $3$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4a_nx^{n+3} = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} 4a_{n-3}x^n.$$

So the rule is "whatever you increase $n$ by in the summand, decrease it in the limits."

After this, your equation should look like

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n+1)a_{n+1} x^n - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n  +\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} 4a_{n-3}x^n.$$

Then peal off the first two terms of the first two sums to get

$$1(2)a_2x +2(3)a_3x^2 -2a_2x - 3a_3x^2 + \sum_{n+3}^{\infty} \mbox{stuff}. $$

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is exactly what I do, but then I get stuck trying to figure out how to make all the summations start at the same indices since that is one of the thing we're trying to do

Comment: @RonaldB  OK, at this point you find the largest lower limit and start all the summations at that point.  Take the extra terms from the other series and combine them into a polynomial at the front.

Comment: @RonaldB See edit.